# Use security in tcp connection

Tags: c#, tcp, ssl

I need to connect a remote server using TCP. the connection need to be secure (SSL/TLS).
The question is how can I open a secure connection to the server?
Does .net framework have the ability?
(I am using c#)
Thank you,
Alon,

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# (forget to say)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class in .NET framework, or our [SSL components](http://www.eldos.com/net-ssl.php) if you need advanced functionality and complete control.

Answer (score 2):

The most common and probably one of the best libraries is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org)

**UPDATE**

[.NET wrapper for OpenSSL library](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: From when did it start to be used in managed .NET applications as "most common"?

Comment: Did I say anything about .NET? There were 2 questions - about ways and .net. And there are no c# or .net tags attached to this question. BUT you can you see `stl` tag?

Comment: I forget to mention that I am using c#. And mistakenly tag as 'stl' instead of 'tsl'

Comment: @Elalfer read the question more attentively. .NET developer asking for SSL - does he care about unix or PHP in this particular question?

Comment: @Anibas I've fixed the tag for you. It must be TLS in fact (Transport Layer Security)

Comment: He didn't say that he is using .net in his original post. and BTW http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/ is OpenSSL wrapper for .NET

Comment: @Elalfer if you look at revisions, you will read about .NET in the very first post. Yes, there exist some wrappers, but they are not popular at all, and I doubt that very usable either (i.e. they are most likely incomplete)